# Include a separate config file in ~/.subversion/config file

Tags: svn, configuration, configuration-files

I have a set of custom configs that I have defined in my `~/.subversion/config` file. I want to use this across multiple machines, but don't want to share the entire `config` file.

In `~/.bashrc` I have the following line for including additional files.

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

How can I something similar for `~/.subversion/config` file?